# How does one determine the maximum resolution supported by a graphics card or integrated chipset?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, resolution, integrated-graphics

How does one determine the maximum resolution supported by a discrete graphics card or integrated graphics chipset within Windows?  The *within Windows* part is key.

It appears that Windows 7 will limit its options to whatever display is connected.  How does one determine the maximum resolution supported by the graphics card or integrated chipset itself (that Windows 7 will support)?

Sometimes, the information provided by the manufacturer does not match the capabilities actually supported, so answers should not be "look it up on the manufacturer's website".

Answer (score 1):

.Try running the following command at a Windows PowerShell prompt:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_VideoControllerResolution|select Caption
```

This queries the operating system (WMI) for the resolutions supported by the video controller.

I'm not completely certain but I believe all of the information about a graphics card and it's capabilities is reported to Windows by the device driver, if this is the case then Windows will only be able to report resolutions the card reports supporting.

Forcing the card into unsupported configurations may be possible with third party software on Windows and is achievable on Linux. Doing this is risky since the card is unlikely to have been tested in unsupported configurations.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you recommended, but I ran into a little issue.  Exact steps: (1) Click on Start Menu (2) Type 'power' (3) Click on Windows PowerShell (4) Type the command you specified.  Result: "The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable function."

Comment: This might be due to your PowerShell version. You may need to upgrade to 3.0 or later. To check your version type 
`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` at a powershell prompt. I'll update my answer to reflect this info and explain the upgrade process in a few minutes

Comment: I think (but not sure) that it may be tied to OS version too. I think you need 8 or newer for this to work.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I've made a slight change to the command. This should work as far back as PowerShell 2.0

Comment: That command gives me a nice little list of resolutions, limited it seems by the maximum horiz. and vert. resolutions of the currently attached monitor, but by no means the output capabilities of the graphics hardware/driver.

Comment: Makes sense. The driver is only going to report what is actually supported. How do you determine the card is capable of more than the manufacturer suggests? It might be a case of just trying to set resolutions

Comment: @Crippledsmurf I think what kreemoweet is saying is that it shows what the display supports, not the graphics chipset.  I tried the command, and it works great (+1), but I'm not sure if it is showing what the graphics card supports or what the display supports.  Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation for CIM_VideoControllerResolution reads: " CIM_VideoControllerResolution class represents the various video modes that a video controller can support. Video modes are defined by the possible horizontal and vertical resolutions, refresh rate, scan mode, and number of color settings supported by a controller. The actual resolutions in use are the values specified in the CIM_VideoController object" This suggests it is returning what the controller supports, assuming you have WDDM drivers Documentation cited is:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Crippledsmurf That sounds like exactly the correct data! Thanks. Can anyone verify that this returns the data for the video controller, regardless of the monitor being used?

Comment: This actually returns the supported resolutions for the current active combination. Just tried it on a laptop which supports 4K output on an external monitor, but when just the internal LCD is connected, it only returns up to 1920x1080.